# How to import an individual local html file in angular4

Tags: html, angular, iframe

There is a iframe:

```
<iframe></iframe>
```

another js will add "src=xxx.html" dynamically into the iframe label.
And the xxx.html is a local file,  the web console shows:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'xxx.html'
```

which directory should I put the individual local html file in, for angular4 project?

Answer (score -1):

Where your xxx.html files?

```
<iframe name="xxx" src="location your xxx.html files"></iframe>
```

Comment: no, the js will set the iframe src automatically, so we can't do that manually.